# Editting Raspberry Pi kernel's bluetooth parameters?

Tags: linux-kernel, raspberry-pi, bluez

I have a 2015 Raspberry Pi 3 B, kernel version 4.14.30. As per [this unsolved BLE BlueZ issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43529336/bluez-5-unknown-connection-identifier) I'm trying to edit include/net/bluetooth/hci.h with the following:

```
#define HCI_LE_CONN_TIMEOUT msecs_to_jiffies(10000) /* 10 seconds WAS 2 seconds */
#define HCI_LE_AUTOCONN_TIMEOUT msecs_to_jiffies(10000) /* 10 seconds WAS 2 seconds */
```

The discussion did not talk about how this is done nor could I find information elsewhere. How can this be accomplished?

Comment: Open it in a text editor and change it. Are you asking how to compile the kernel?

Comment: The original include file sets `HCI_LE_CONN_TIMEOUT` to 20 seconds  (`msecs_to_jiffies(20000)`) and sets `HCI_LE_AUTOCONN_TIMEOUT` to 2 seconds. In the 4.15 kernel, `HCI_LE_AUTOCONN_TIMEOUT` was increased to 4 seconds by [commit 1f01d8be0e6a](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/include/net/bluetooth/hci.h?id=1f01d8be0e6a04bd682a55f6d50c14c1679e7571). Perhaps you could request a backport to 4.14.y of that commit on the Linux "stable" mailing list <stable@vger.kernel.org>.

Comment: There is general information on recompiling Raspberry Pi kernels on [Kernel Building](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/linux/kernel/building.md). You will need to edit that include file after getting the kernel sources before you build (`make`) the kernel.