# 5.0 bluetooth device on raspberry pi 3

Tags: bluetooth, raspberry-pi

I am trying to connect RN4870 devices to a raspberry pi 3 B running jessie 2017-07-05. This bluetooth chip has been updated in April 2019 from Bluetooth 4.2 to 5.0 and I can connect to the older ones but not to new ones.
I am trying to connect them through "bluetoothctl". All devices are detected but connection only works with the older ones.

I red that bluetooth 4.2 and 5.0 should be compatible, but it does not work (instantly disconnect):

```
[CHG] Device 04:91:62:9E:8F:9A Connected: yes
Failed to connect: org.bluez.Error.Failed
[CHG] Device 04:91:62:9E:8F:9A Connected:
```

I tried the same connection with a raspberry pi 4 with raspbian 2020 and everything works fine.

Any idea where this comes from ?

EDIT : I installed a fresh image on the same rpi3 and all devices connect, must be some parameters I must find

Comment: I suspect the version of BlueZ is dramatically different between the two OS versions. You can find this out with `bluetoothctl version`. Take a look at release notes to see if there is anything obvious (http://www.bluez.org/). Also, in another terminal have running `sudo btmon -t` when you do the connect, this should give you more information with which to debug the issue.

Comment: versions are different : 5.43 for rpi3 and 5.50 for rpi4. I didn't notice anything in the change logs
Error is "Status: Unknown Connection Identifier (0x02)" after connection.
same problem on this topic :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43529336/bluez-5-unknown-connection-identifier

I don't need the lastest version of bluez, so I installed v5.23 which worked for them but it not for me. I didn't try the timeout solution of the topic because v5.23 would work otherwise.

I noticed that once I have a failed connection, I cannot connect anymore with any devices.

Comment: I think that other question is talking about something different. You are talking about Bluetooth Core Specification 5.0 (https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/bluetooth-core-specification/) while the other question is talking about the difficult transition to BlueZ 5 (http://www.bluez.org/release-of-bluez-5-0/) . BlueZ 5.45 release notes: "This is mostly a bugfix release with fixes in ATT, GATT, OBEX and AVDTP. Feature-wise there are some new things as well, such as btmon support decoding Bluetooth 5.0 HCI commands and events.". Downgrading from 5.43 to 5.23 seems to be going the wrong way

Comment: did some testing: it does not work with newer versions (5.50 or 5.54) on rpi3. It does work on ubutu with all the versions I tried. I added a 4.0 tp link bluetooth dongle from amazon on the rpi 3 and it works.